# Passing a List from Controller to View in MVC - Can't get string using foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass a List from my controller to a view.

The model as defined in my view is:

```
@model List<prismic.starter.Models.ResourceModel>
```

I am passing a `List<ResourceModel>` from my controller to the view:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> resources()
    {
        var docArray = await new Prismic_Connect().getAllByType("resource");
        List<ResourceModel> resourceList = new List<ResourceModel>();
        foreach(var doc in docArray)
        {
            resourceList.Add(new ResourceModel(doc));
        }
        return View(resourceList);
    }
```

I can get the string value I am trying to display by writing the following:

```
@Model.First().getTitle();
```

However, when I try to loop through the list using `foreach` , the "title" string is not displayed.

```
@{ 
   foreach (var doc in Model)
   {
      doc.getTitle();
   }
 }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missing the leading `@` which tells the razor engine to output the value

```
@foreach (var doc in Model)
{
    @doc.getTitle(); // add @
}
```